# Why does this way of calculating $ \int\frac{dt}{\cos(t)}$ fail?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a problem trying to solve the differential equation: $y'= \sqrt{1+y^2}$

The steps that I follow are:
$$ y'= \sqrt{1+y^2} \implies \int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=\int dx 
$$ by defining $ y=\tan{(t)}$ in order to calculate the first integral we get:
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{d(\tan{(t)})}{dt}=\frac{1}{\cos^2{(t)}}\implies dy=\frac{dt}{\cos^2(t)}$$ making the substitution of change of variables in the $y$ integral we get:
$$ \int\frac{dt}{\cos(t)}$$ I know what this integral is equal to but I tried an alternative way to calculate it:
I used the fact that the integral:
$$ \int\frac{dx}{1-x^2}$$ when making a substitution $x=\sin(t)$ transforms to $$\int\frac{dt}{\cos(t)} $$ However the integral above can be easily calculated by breaking it down to fractions as equal to $$\frac{1}{2}\ln{ \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)}+C $$ which gives us a result $$\int\frac{dt}{\cos(t)}=\frac{1}{2}\ln{ \left(\frac{1+\sin(t)}{1-\sin(t)} \right)}+C  $$ which does not coincide however with the result that I am aware of: $$\int\frac{dt}{\cos(t)}=\ln{(|\tan(x)+\sec(x)|)} +C $$
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are one and the same! $\frac {1+\sin t} {1-\sin t}=\frac {(1+\sin t)^{2}} {1-\sin^{2}t}$ and $\frac {1+\sin t} {|\cos t|} =|\tan t +\sec t|$.

Comment: The one-half is the square root between the first and second lines.

Comment: For clarification $(1+\sin x)^2=1+2\sin x+\sin^2 x$, so $\frac{1+2\sin x+\sin^2x}{\cos^2 x}=\sec^2 x+2\sin x\sec x+\tan^2x=(\sec x+\tan x)^2$.